# Public CSS doesnt work in another page in React

Tags: html, css

I have public CSS on my public/index.html and I used it like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
```

assets/css/style.css also in public folder. Its working fine on my home page but its not working on my second page. What is wrong in here ? Thanks for helps!

Answer (score 0):

Step:1 - Keep you style.css inside `src/assets/css`

Step:2 - Remove `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />` from public/index.html

Step:3 - import style inside `src/index.js` by using import statement, like:

```
import './assets/css/style.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ES6 import statements, like `import './assets/css/style.css';`

Don't add stylesheet link tags to your HTML file if you're using a framework/library like react.